# Grails 3 - GORM for MongoDB - nearest read for replica set

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails3

I'm upgrading my Grails 2.4 web application to Grails 3, and I'm considering switching from my custom DAO to GORM for my Mongo database.

I'm trying to understand how to setup GORM correctly, in particular about connection `options`, but its documentation is slightly misleading to me.
The [Advanced Configuration](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/index.html#advancedConfig) ("Mongo Database Connection Configuration") states

> Available options and their descriptions are defined in the [MongoOptions](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.html) javadoc.

so I'm tempted to assume that I'm allowed to use any of those options.

But later on in the same section (Configuration Options Guide) I read

> Below is a complete example showing **all** configuration options:

showing only 9 options.

My issue is 'converting' my custom DAO

```
MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClientOptions .Builder()
                                                    .connectionsPerHost(1000)
                                                    .threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(5)
                                                    .maxWaitTime(4000)
                                                    .socketTimeout(2000).build();
List<ServerAddress> list = getMongoReplicaSet();
mongo = new MongoClient(list, options);
mongo.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.nearest());
```

to an equivalent configuration

```
grails {
    mongodb {
        options {
            connectionsPerHost = 1000
            threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier = 5
            maxWaitTime = 4000
            socketTimeout = 2000
        }
    }
}
```

but how to define the read preference? Am I allowed to do something like this?

```
grails {
    mongodb {
        options {
            readPreference = com.mongodb.ReadPreference.nearest()
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can set anything in the [MongoClientOptions.Builder](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html) class via configuration. Although you syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
grails {
   mongodb {
      options {
        readPreference = com.mongodb.ReadPreference.nearest()
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! :)
Sorry for my typo, question updated with correct syntax.